# Why is this program that should take 11 input end after only taking a single input?

Tags: c

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct date
    {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    };
    struct address
    {
        char city[15];
        char district[15];
    };
    struct student
    {
        char name[25];
        int roll_no;
        struct date DOB;
        struct address add;
    };
    struct student BIM[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter student name: ");
        scanf("%s",BIM[i].name);
        printf("Enter roll no: ");
        scanf("%d",&BIM[i].roll_no);
        printf("Enter Date of birth: ");
        scanf("%d %d %d",BIM[i].DOB.year,BIM[i].DOB.month,BIM[i].DOB.day);
        printf("Enter address: ");
        scanf("%s %s",BIM[i].add.district,BIM[i].add.city);
    }
    int roll;
    printf("Enter roll no: ");
    scanf("%d",&roll);
    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        if(roll==BIM[i].roll_no)
        {
            printf("Name : %s",BIM[i].name);
            printf("Roll no : %d",BIM[i].roll_no);
            printf("DOB : %d/%d/%d",BIM[i].DOB.year,BIM[i].DOB.month,BIM[i].DOB.day);
            printf("Address : %s,%s",BIM[i].add.district,BIM[i].add.city);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The program ends after taking DOB during the 1st loop.

Here are the warnings:

```
main.c:32:17: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d %d %d",BIM[i].DOB.year,BIM[i].DOB.month,BIM[i].DOB.day);


main.c:32:20: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d %d %d",BIM[i].DOB.year,BIM[i].DOB.month,BIM[i].DOB.day);


main.c:32:23: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d %d %d",BIM[i].DOB.year,BIM[i].DOB.month,BIM[i].DOB.day);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the warnings or why the program does not wait for more input?

Comment: As the warnings tell you, you provide wrong paramters to `scanf`. If you pass an integer while an address is expected, you are causing undefined behaviour which might result in a crash. Also you should always check return value of any I/O function like `scanf`.

Comment: You have an array of *ten* elements, and want to use *eleven* elements in that array? That makes no sense.

Comment: As for why the program quits, not using the correct type of argument to `printf` invokes undefined behaviour, which in this case results in the program just crashing out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `&` there.

Comment: That's a bit short for a good answer. You might a bit more explanation. Also it only addresses the warnings, not the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to use the `&` character when using `scanf` on variables which are not pointers or arrays, since `scanf` requires the memory location of the variable you're using to store the inputted data, or the first memory location of an array you're trying to fill (which you get by simply addressing the array with its name without indexes).